# Gitlab CI/CD pipeline run/extend other jobs in sequence

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment, gitlab-ci-runner

So I have a job which is triggered with specific rules - creating a new tag `app-prod-1.0.0` or `app-dev-1.0.0`. Whenever new tag is created I call the job, which in return extends other jobs

```
image: node:lts-alpine
stages:
  - install
  - build
  - deploy

.install-packages:
  stage: install
  script:
    - echo "INSTALL-PACKAGES"
    - yarn install --cache-folder .yarn-cache
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - node_modules
  cache:
    - key:
        files:
          - yarn.lock
      paths:
        - .yarn-cache/

.build-project:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "BUILD-PROJECT"
    - echo $ENVIRONMENT
    - yarn build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build

.deploy-project:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "DEPLOY-PROJECT"
    - ls -la build

build_prod:
  variables:
    PACKAGE: '/app/prod'
    ENVIRONMENT: 'prod'
  extends:
    - .install-packages
    - .build-project
    - .deploy-project
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^app-prod-[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/'

build_dev:
  variables:
    PACKAGE: '/app/dev'
    ENVIRONMENT: 'dev'
  extends:
    - .install-packages
    - .build-project
    - .deploy-project
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^app-dev-[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/'
```

My thought was that jobs will be called in the order I have described inside the job: `.install-packages`, `.build-project`, `.deploy-project`. But that's not happening it seems that it just jumps to the last job `.deploy-project`, without installing and building and thus breaking my pipeline.
How to run/extend jobs in sequence?

Answer (score 2):

This is the behaviour for which I didn't use multiple extends so far in my work with GitLab.

GitLab, attempts to merge the code from parent job.

Now all your parent jobs defines the script tag and in your job for e.g. build_prod the extends happening in below order

```
extends:
    - .install-packages
    - .build-project
    - .deploy-project
```

the script code from .deploy-project is overwriting the other job's script tag.

It works differently for the variables. It will merge all the variables and overwrites if same variable is used.

See your own example updated with variables.

```
image: node:lts-alpine
stages:
  - install
  - build
  - deploy

.install-packages:
  stage: install
  variables:
    PACKAGE: 'install'
    INSTALL: 'install'
  script:
    - echo "INSTALL-PACKAGES"
    - yarn install --cache-folder .yarn-cache
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - node_modules
  cache:
    - key:
        files:
          - yarn.lock
      paths:
        - .yarn-cache/

.build-project:
  stage: build
  variables:
    PACKAGE: 'build'
    BUILD: 'build'
  script:
    - echo "BUILD-PROJECT"
    - echo $ENVIRONMENT
    - yarn build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build

.deploy-project:
  stage: deploy
  variables:
    PACKAGE: 'deploy'
    DEPLOY: 'from deploy'
  script:
    - echo "DEPLOY-PROJECT"
    - ls -la build

build_prod:
  variables:
    PACKAGE: '/app/prod'
    ENVIRONMENT: 'prod'
  extends:
    - .install-packages
    - .build-project
    - .deploy-project
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^app-prod-[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/'

build_dev:
  variables:
    PACKAGE: '/app/dev'
    ENVIRONMENT: 'dev'
  extends:
    - .install-packages
    - .build-project
    - .deploy-project
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^app-dev-[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/'
```

And now notice how PACKAGE variable is overwritten with the final value of '/app/prod' which comes from build-prod job itself. At the same time other variables from individual parent jobs are merged to look like below

```
variables:
    PACKAGE: "/app/prod"
    INSTALL: install
    BUILD: build
    DEPLOY: from deploy
    ENVIRONMENT: prod
```

I really found **View merged YAML** feature best to understand how my yml file will be evaluated.

Its available in CI/CD -> Editor

Comment: Is there a way to achieve what bukowski is trying to do if `extends` clause won't merge multiple script clauses that have been extended? I'm having the same issue right now.

Answer (score 0):

It's not actually "jumps to the last job", but simply executes a single job you have provided - that is `build_prod` or `build_dev`, depending on commit tag.

As per [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#extends) when you are calling `extends`, you are basically just merging everything inside all the template jobs that you specified, so the last `stage` keyword, which comes from `.deploy-project` template job wins.

You should specify each job separately for each stage, and maybe even put your `rules` to a separate template job, i.e.

```yaml
.dev:
  variables:
    PACKAGE: '/app/dev'
    ENVIRONMENT: 'dev'
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^app-dev-[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/'
install-dev:
  extends:
    - .dev
    - .install-packages
build-dev:
  extends:
    - .dev
    - .build-project
deploy-dev:
  extends:
    - .dev
    - .deploy-project
```

You should create similar jobs for `prod` env, define template job .prod, and create install-prod, build-prod, deploy-prod jobs